# Most straightforward way to consolidate data from multiple different RDBMS systems into a queryable database

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, firebird, middleware

I have few  tables that I have to sync between 3 different RDBMS systems (PostgreSQL databases, a SQL Server and a Firebird Database).

Currently I simply connect to my Firebird database and pull the few relevant tables to my PostgreSQL database, but as databases change, new tables require querying and with the addition of a SQL Server database to the mix I feel this solution is ill fitting.

I've done some research on BI tools , but I still need to query data from this  data source and show them inside a Windows Forms application.

PS: it's not a migration and I only need to query the data from these "satellite" databases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PostgreSQL as your hub, you can use Foreign Data Wrappers to reach out to the other two databases whenever a query wants their data. Then it will always be up to date, but performance might suffer compared to actually importing the data.  For reaching SQL Server, you can use [tds_fdw](https://github.com/tds-fdw/tds_fdw), and for firebird you can use [firebird_fdw](https://pgxn.org/dist/firebird_fdw).  I have never used either one of these, so this is just a starting point.

You could probably pick SQL Server as your hub and accomplish the same thing, it calls them "linked servers" rather than Foreign Data Wrappers, see [for example](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3662/sql-server-and-postgresql-linked-server-configuration--part-2/).

Comment: I've gone with this one, I've found out that as much as FDW  are great, less popular FDW like firebird's are not as featureful as the ones for  SQL server or oracle